# How to prioritise certain queries in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a large number of background reads and writes, and a much smaller number of user reads, of a highly contended MySQL database - is there any way to flag certain queries (the user queries) as being high priority so that they take preference over background queries? I want user responsiveness to be high, but don't really care about the background queries.

Thanks

Comment: Which storage engine are you using? InnoDB? MyISAM?

Comment: InnoDB but I could switch if there's good reason ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQl supports [`insert delayed`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-delayed.html) for delayed `insert`s and  [`low_priority`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html) for `update`s. And for your user reads, there's the `high_priority` extension on [`select`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html). If you're using the MyISAM storage engine, there's the related (but different) [concurrent inserts](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/concurrent-inserts.html) feature.

Comment: On the other hand, `SELECT` supports the `HIGH_PRIORITY` keyword, which give selects the same priority as an update.

Comment: @Romuald: Apparently I was editing my answer as you commented. :-)

Comment: Am i correct in thinking that if there are no high priority selects all low priority inserts and updates would just operate at normal priority?

Comment: also, does a high priority select override a low priority update? thanks

Comment: @Malcolm: The linked docs suggest there's an overhead to low-priority stuff, so it wouldn't be free. Re your second question, again deferring to the docs but I'm pretty sure that's the point, yes. I think even a normal select is less-impacted by a low-priority update (for instance) and that a high-priority select is scheduled more aggressively over other statements, including other selects. The only way to know how this will play out with your schema and such is to give it a whirl, but you're at least telling the DBMS what *you* think is a priority.

Comment: The thing they don't seem to offer that I've wanted more than once is a *low-priority* select, a "get to this whenever you get to it," for ad hoc admin queries. But I guess I really shouldn't be doing ad hoc admin queries on the live DB; I should be using a replicated server or a snapshot. Ah, well... :-)

Comment: Mysql Insert Delayed

Unfortunatelly it is not available on innodb.

Comment: @saun4frsh and `delayed` is deprecated now.