# How can priority be given to write/update over read in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, concurrency, innodb

In my application, I want any insert to the database to be executed as soon as a request comes for writing some data.

I am using InnoDB engine.

Since insertion requires an exclusive lock, it is possible that while current read query has a shared lock, some other reads might come which again have a shared lock and the write operation might have to wait for a long time.

I want that when there is a write operation in queue, no read operation gets a shared lock. As soon as the reads which were initiated before the current write request are completed, the write operation should be executed. After that all other read operations should take place.

How can this be implemented?

### Edit

Since I am using InnoDB tables and I am not implementing table lock, there should not be a conflict between select and insert. It would be select and update. (Please correct me if there can be a conflict between select and insert as well)

In MySQL, update has higher priority than select. But if there are some read queries being executed, then update query comes in followed by some read queries. In that case, will the read queries coming after update wait for the update to finish as mentioned here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//table-locking.html OR they will get shared lock along with the read queries which were there before the update query was fired?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408278/how-to-prioritise-certain-queries-in-mysql

Comment: Are you talking about a single or multiple-many sessions firing the queries?

Comment: @Suresh Kamrushi, My question is a bit different. I want to have high priority for insert than select.

Comment: @Michel Feldheim, There are multiple sessions.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to acquire shared locks when reading from the database. In fact, with the default transaction isolation level [REPEATABLE READ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_repeatable-read) ordinary `SELECT` queries within one transaction read from a consistent snapshot. No locks are acquired and required, within this transaction you will simply not see any changes committed in other transactions.

Since no shared locks are acquired, exclusive locks for updating queries are immediately granted to other sessions in the order they are filed.

MySQL doc says the following

> Consistent read is the default mode in which InnoDB processes SELECT statements in READ COMMITTED and REPEATABLE READ isolation levels. A consistent read does not set any locks on the tables it accesses, and therefore other sessions are free to modify those tables at the same time a consistent read is being performed on the table.
>
> Suppose that you are running in the default REPEATABLE READ isolation level. When you issue a consistent read (that is, an ordinary SELECT statement), InnoDB gives your transaction a timepoint according to which your query sees the database. If another transaction deletes a row and commits after your timepoint was assigned, you do not see the row as having been deleted. Inserts and updates are treated similarly.

Comment: @Michael Feldheim, thanks for the explanation. I had not understood this well.
I tried reading and writing from two transactions at the same time. But the transaction other than the one from which insert was executed also shows the inserted row. I have set autocommit=0 and isolation level to repeatable read

Comment: Did you do this from two different clients / sessions? Which MySQL version are you running? This statements should be valid since MySQL 5.0

Comment: I am using MySQL 4.1
Will upgrade to latest version.
Is the old version the reason for this?

Comment: This is very old. At MySQL 4.x it didn't deserve the title database management system. Are you able to update? This is recommended a lot. Take [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html) and [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/upgrading.html) as a reference for upgrading

Answer (score 0):

You can try looking at `INSERT DELAYED` [Mysql Insert Delayed](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-delayed.html)

Unfortunatelly it is not available on innodb.

PS: A exclusive lock cannot be acquired if there is already a shared lock on the table. So basicly, in your situation: 3 reads obtain a shared lock, one insert needs exclusive lock. The insert will only be able to obtain the lock after the selects have finished.

Comment: The situation you have given is fine. But the one I want to handle is different. There are 3 reads which have acquired a shared lock. An update needs exclusive lock which it will not be granted. 2 more read queries come in. They will be granted shared lock. I want the 2 select queries to wait, i.e. if there is an update in queue, further select queries should wait before that update is executed. How can this be implemented?